# React component rendering even when there is no change in the state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

From the React Docs, what I have learnt is that the component will re-render only if there is a change in the value of a state.

For instance

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  console.log("I am rendering");

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    setCount(0);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Increment</button>
      Count value is: {count}
    </>
  );
}
```

The message `I am rendering` is printed only **once** even if we click the button because the `setCount` function is setting the value to `0` which is the present value of `count`

Since there is no change in the present and future value therefore, the Component does not re-render.

### Unexpected Behaviour

However, the similar behaviour is not observed when we add an extra line `setCount(1)` before `setCount(0)`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  console.log("I am rendering");

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    setCount(1); //this line has been added extra
    setCount(0);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Increment</button>
      Count value is: {count}
    </>
  );
}
```

In principle, there is no change in the output of the final `count` value. However, if we click the button, the component re-renders and prints the message `I am rendering`

---

I could not find an explanation for this behaviour. Is this behaviour on expected lines?.

*Shouldn't the component re-render only when the final value of the state is different from the current value ?*

Comment: See [Bailing out of a state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update)... _"If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects"_. The inverse of that being if you do update a state hook, it **will** render children and fire effects. Calling `setCount()` with a new value is updating the state hook

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes, Reacts needs another render phase to decide if it needs a bailout. By the way, when we saying "bailout" meaning bailing out the [Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) process.

Notice the documentation on [Bailing out a state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update):

> Note that React **may still need to render that specific component again before bailing out**.

Here is another example of such case demonstrating the idea:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("B");
  }, [state]);

  console.log("A");

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{state}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setState(42)}>Click</button>
    </>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[image: Edit React state trigger]

You notice the next logs and their explanations:

```
A // First render
B // Mount

A // State change from 0 -> 42, triggers render
B // useEffect dep array change, triggers callback

A // **Our issue**, React needs another render
```

Answer (score 0):

The value does change when you press the button. First, it changes to 1 then to 0 but this runs very fast that you don't get to see it.

to see this, you could add a setTimeout

```js
const handleButtonClick = () => {
  setCount(1); //this line has been added extra
  setTimeout(() => {
    setCount(0);
  }, 500);
};
```

Comment: Thats not the reason, the calls in OP question are batched i.e there is a single state change. Its not "very fast".