# Is it possible to happen that only father component rerender and child one doesn't?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm researching the timing of re-render when state setter function is called today.

In my acknowledgement, if I click "setNumber to 9" button, it won't activate re-render, because the value of state is the same.

Likewise, If I click "setNumber to 10" button, it will activate re-render, because the value of state is the different, I can see both two components console.log message in concole.

Here comes the weird thing I couldn't understand.

After clicking "setNumber to 10" button once, I click "setNumber to 10" button again. I thought it won't activate re-render, because number is still 10. However, App.jsx did re-render, and the message showed in console. Another weird thing is that even component "App" re-render then, "Num" component didn't.

Why would this happened?

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Num from "./Components/Num";

function App() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(9);

  console.log("Component 'App' just re-render.");

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>If we setNumber to same value, will react do re-render？</h1>
      <Num number={number} />
      <button className="firstBtn" onClick={() => setNumber(9)}>
        setNumber to 9
      </button>
      <button className="btn" onClick={() => setNumber(10)}>
        setNumber to 10
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
const Num = ({ number }) => {
  console.log("Component 'num' just re-render.");

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
      }}
    >
      <h3 style={{ marginRight: "8px", color: "#ff5fa2" }}>Number:</h3>
      <h3>{number}</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Num;
```

I checked document of React to make sure they did use `object.is()` to check if states are same or not. If they are the name, it won't re-render.

Also I try to wrap `memo` on component Num. However, result was the same.

Comment: You are console logging as an unintentional side-effect, so it's not an accurate measure of any component rendering ***to the DOM***. Move the console logs into a `useEffect` hook. It's known that setting state to the same as the current value that React may rerender the component 1 more additional time. The `memo` Higher Order Component can be used to keep a component from rerendering by comparing previous and current props values.

Comment: Related: [React component rendering even when there is no change in the state value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71749703) and [Why React needs another render to bail out state updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69937709)

Comment: FWIW it's that "one more additional render" that React figures out it doesn't need to go further down the ReactTree, e.g. why `Num` doesn't rerender the second time.

Comment: You are not checking for a re render in a useEffect. Having a console log outside of a use effect will not truly reflect a re-render.

Comment: Thanks for all replies above, I get it now. Really appreciate.